# How to draw the route using google map direction in swift?

Tags: swift, google-maps

I am developing my own iOS app using swift.
I am facing an issue with google map direction now.
I can't draw the route from two coordinate using google map direction now.

Below shows the code.

```
func drawRoute(from source: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to destination: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
                        
        let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin= \(source.latitude),\(source.longitude)&destination=\(destination.latitude),\(destination.longitude)&mode=driving&key=\(GoogleMapKey.directionKey)"
        
        self.showLoadingView()
        
        print(url)
                
        AF.request(url, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in

            self.hideLoadingView()
            
            switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    print("************")
                    print(JSON(value))
                    let jsonData = JSON(value)
                    let routes = jsonData["routes"].arrayValue
                    
                    for route in routes {
                        let overview_polyline = route["overview_polyline"].dictionaryValue
                        let points = overview_polyline["points"]!.stringValue

                        self.drawPath(from: points)
                        ProgressHUD.showError("success")
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    ProgressHUD.showError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

Could you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use this method for routes creation. Firstly it will try to create route in GoogleMaps app. If user don't have google maps app, default Maps app will be launched.

```
func openMaps(lat: Double, lng: Double) {
    if let googleMapsUrl = URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(lat),\(lng)&directionsmode=driving"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(googleMapsUrl) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(googleMapsUrl)
    } else {
        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng), addressDictionary: nil)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = "Target location"
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this would require the browser opening.. sorry.

Comment: Browser opening? This code opens GoogleMaps application or AppleMaps application. Or I have misunderstood and you need to open browser?